# Import Simple Json into Sql table via Azure Datafactory V2

Tags: json, database, azure, azure-data-factory

I want to copy Daily JSON files from Azure Datalake V2 blob into Azure Sql database Table

--Simple JSON code structure

```
{
    "EmpRec": [{
            "PersNo": 5553345,
            "FirstName": "David",
            "LastName": "Bishop",
            "ContrType": "Permanent",
            "Age": 45,
            "Length": 5,
            "Wsr": "1001WK01 ",
            "WorkSchedule": "Office Workers ",
            "OctTHome": "35,12",
            "SeptTHome": "50,40",
            "AugTHome": "10,0",
            "Site": "Home Depot",
            "SDate": "2012-04-17 ",
            "EDate": "2016-04-17 ",
            "Status": "Active",
            "Group": "Citizen",
            "Subarea": "Citizen",
            "SubGroup": "Citizen",
            "Position": "Driver",
            "Organization": "Loading RD"
        }, {
            "PersNo": 5553346,
            "FirstName": "Norris",
            "LastName": "OFdachuck",
            "ContrType": "Permanent",
            "Age": 42,
            "Length": 2,
            "Wsr": "1001WK012",
            "WorkSchedule": "Office Workers ",
            "OctTHome": "66,35",
            "SeptTHome": "72,32",
            "AugTHome": "68,02",
            "Site": "Normandy",
            "SDate": "2012-04-17 ",
            "EDate": "2016-04-17 ",
            "Status": "Active",
            "Group": "Citizen",
            "Subarea": "Citizen",
            "SubGroup": "Citizen",
            "Position": "Driver",
            "Organization": "Loading RD"
        }, {
            "PersNo": 5553347,
            "FirstName": "List",
            "LastName": "Forbes",
            "ContrType": "Permanent",
            "Age": 30,
            "Length": 1,
            "Wsr": "1001WK011",
            "WorkSchedule": "Office Workers ",
            "OctTHome": "35,12",
            "SeptTHome": "68,02",
            "AugTHome": "66,31",
            "Site": "Normandy",
            "SDate": "2012-04-17 ",
            "EDate": "2016-04-17 ",
            "Status": "Active",
            "Group": "Citizen",
            "Subarea": "Citizen",
            "SubGroup": "Citizen",
            "Position": "Driver",
            "Organization": "Loading RD"
        }, {
            "PersNo": 5553348,
            "FirstName": "Childs",
            "LastName": "Play",
            "ContrType": "Delivery",
            "Age": 25,
            "Length": 3,
            "Wsr": "1001WK10",
            "WorkSchedule": "Office Workers ",
            "OctTHome": "Office Workers ",
            "SeptTHome": "50,40",
            "AugTHome": "10,0",
            "Site": "Balamb Garden",
            "SDate": "2012-04-17 ",
            "EDate": "2016-04-17 ",
            "Status": "Active",
            "Group": "Citizen",
            "Subarea": "Citizen",
            "SubGroup": "Citizen",
            "Position": "Driver",
            "Organization": "Loading RD"
        }, {
            "PersNo": 5553349,
            "FirstName": "Rob",
            "LastName": "Black",
            "ContrType": "Permanent",
            "Age": 28,
            "Length": 10,
            "Wsr": "1001WK05",
            "WorkSchedule": "Packing",
            "OctTHome": "66,35",
            "SeptTHome": "72,32",
            "AugTHome": "68,02",
            "Site": "Fisherman's Horizon",
            "SDate": "2012-04-17 ",
            "EDate": "2016-04-17 ",
            "Status": "Active",
            "Group": "Citizen",
            "Subarea": "Citizen",
            "SubGroup": "Citizen",
            "Position": "Driver",
            "Organization": "Loading RD"
        }
    ]
```

Expected the 5 records to be uploaded, but only the first record loads. Is there any good tutorials on loading JSON to SQL? Can ADFV2 handle this or should i just revert to OPENJSON ?

Comment: Seriously need to get my editing skills. Seeing that I will be sleeping on stackoverflow. Thanks Joy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json is a supported file format, you have to create a dataset and configure it properly. Remember to use the "preview data" button to see if the configurations are working before publishing a pipeline and running it.

Link to the doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-json

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks Martin, This helps

Answer (score 0):

so I managed to extract some Azure SQL data to JSON and here's the caveat. JSON like XML has multiple structures. Make sure your JSON is in it's flattest form for ADFV2 data import and exports.

[image: JSON on the left is flat JSON on the right has table object as top level]

Assuming the JSON on the right could potentially load multiple tables, just not sure if ADFV2 is at this point able to Copy any JSON format to Azure SQL DB tables.